# Why not close modal window?CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css, modal-dialog

I have this modal window

https://jsfiddle.net/wxorg152/

(seen bad because I copied from the site and CSS code as there's not)

The window opens problem is not going to close ... how can I close it?

**CODE HTML:**

```
<div class="border"><a id="gigi" href="#modal">Tabel Dimensiuni</a></div>

<div class="md-modal" id="modal">
    <div class="md-content">
        <h3>Modal Dialog</h3>
        <div>
<a class="md-close" href="#">Close me!</a>
                        <p class="titlu-modal">Dimensiuni pentru lenjerie</p>
            <img src="http://www.altradona.ro/media/wysiwyg/DIMENSIUNI-PENTRU-LENJERIE.png" >
            <p class="titlu-modal">Dimensiuni pentru dresuri</p>
                        <img src="http://www.altradona.ro/media/wysiwyg/DIMENSIUNI-PENTRU-DRESURI.png" >
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="md-overlay"></div>
```

**CODE CSS:**

```
#overlay {
     visibility: hidden;
     position: absolute;
     left: 0px;
     top: 0px;
     width:100%;
     height:100%;
     text-align:center;
     z-index: 1000;
}


#overlay div {
     width:300px;
     margin: 100px auto;
     background-color: #fff;
     border:1px solid #000;
     padding:15px;
     text-align:center;
}

.border{border-bottom:1px solid rgba(227,227,227,0.61);}




#gigi {

  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
gigi:hover {
  background-color: #a5281b;
}


.md-modal {
    position: fixed;
    top: 55%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    max-width: 630px;
    min-width: 320px;
    height: auto;
    z-index: 1000;
    visibility: hidden;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

.md-modal:target {
    visibility: visible;
}

.md-overlay {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    visibility: hidden;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    opacity: 0;
    background: transparent;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

.md-modal:target ~ .md-overlay {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}

/* Content styles */
.md-content {
    color: #fff;
    background: url(http://www.altradona.ro/media/wysiwyg/BODY.png) ;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.md-content h3 {
display:none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0.4em;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2.4em;
    font-weight: 300;
    opacity: 0.8;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
}

.md-content > div {
    padding: 15px 40px 30px;
    margin: 0;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 1.15em;
}

.md-content > div p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 0;
}

.md-content > div ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 30px 20px;
}

.md-content > div ul li {
    padding: 5px 0;
}

.md-content a {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size: 0.8em;
float:right;
}

/* Effect */

.md-modal .md-content {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.7);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.7);
    -ms-transform: scale(0.7);
    transform: scale(0.7);
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

.titlu-modal img
{
    width:50px;
}
.md-modal:target .md-content {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
}
```

I put an image to understand better what I want to do

http://i60.tinypic.com/nbcghg.jpg

I want to close the window and unfortunately does not work ... you can help me solve this problem please?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dialog is not closing because you have an overlay div (class `md-overlay`) on top of everything. Basically the click doesn't even reach the 'close' button.

HTML

```
<div class="border"><a id="gigi" href="#modal">Tabel Dimensiuni</a></div>

<div class="md-modal" id="modal">
    <div class="md-content">
        <h3>Modal Dialog</h3>
        <div>
<a class="md-close" href="#">Close me!</a>
                        <p class="titlu-modal">Dimensiuni pentru lenjerie</p>
            <img src="http://www.altradona.ro/media/wysiwyg/DIMENSIUNI-PENTRU-LENJERIE.png" >
            <p class="titlu-modal">Dimensiuni pentru dresuri</p>
                        <img src="http://www.altradona.ro/media/wysiwyg/DIMENSIUNI-PENTRU-DRESURI.png" >
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- **************************************** -->
         <div class="md-overlay"></div>
<!-- **************************************** -->
```

CSS

```
.md-overlay {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    visibility: hidden;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    opacity: 0;
    background: transparent;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}
```